# I can't use .src with .pathname in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, path

I'm trying to use a code to compare the image's path that is displaying to the relative path independent of the url, but .pathname isn't working

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>change images</title>
        <script>
            var img=document.getElementById('img').src;
            function change(){
                if(img.pathname='img1.png'){
                    var next='img2.png';
                    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML='img2.png';
                }else if(img.pathname='img2.png'){
                    var next='img1.png';
                    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML='img1.png';
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML='error';
                }

                document.getElementById('img').src=next;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id='img' src="img1.png">
        <button id='btn' onclick="change()">change</button>
    </body>
<html>
```

on console it 'says' that img isn't an object

I tried to look for what `img.pathname` returns and it returned `undefined`

Comment: Check your conditionals. `=` is the assignment operator, `===` is the comparison operator.

Comment: Paste your code into jshint.com and fix all warnings it shows you. Using tools like this is a very good habit to get into (you can integrate them directly into many editors, too). There are a few other mistakes in this code, too.

Comment: `img` and `.src` is a string.

Comment: Daniel A. White, Is there a way to change .src type from string to path or something?

Comment: **omg** isn't an object? :-) I think you meant to say `img` isn't an object. And, besides, you need to change the var declaration to `var img = document.getElementById('img');`, i.e. drop the .src suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pathname isn't a property of the image element.  From looking at your code it's clear you just want the filename of the image, without the path.  This will do that for you...

```
function change() {
    // get everything after the last / in the image src attribute
    var current = document.getElementById('img').src.split("/").slice(-1);

    if (current == 'img1.png') {
        var next = 'img2.png';
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'img2.png';
    }
    else if (current == 'img2.png') {
        var next = 'img1.png';
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'img1.png';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = 'error';
    }

    document.getElementById('img').src = next;
}
```

It splits the image src attribute at each instance of `/` into an array, and then `slice` cuts it at a specific index, in this case the last element, so that's all you get.

Also, notice the use of `==` when comparing values.  If you have...

```
if (current = "something)
```

then it actually sets current to the value "something" (because of the single `=`) and the if statement evaluates as true.

Comment: thanks for your solution and I saw that you used the src again in the third line and img already have this suffix. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using `indexOf()` to search for the image name in the `.src` string.

```
<script>

    function change(){
        var img=document.getElementById('img').src;
        if (img.indexOf('img1.png')!= -1){
            var next='img2.png';
        } else if (img.indexOf('img2.png')!= -1) {
            var next='img1.png';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML='else';
        }


        document.getElementById('img').src=next;
        document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML=next;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That will work with this specific example, but it will also work if the image src *ends with* `img1.png` or `img2.png`.  If you use an image called `this-is-not-img1.png` then your code would treat it as if it was `img1.png`.  It's better to get the actual filename of the image, rather than check that a string exists within it.